# unable to configure php designer 8 with wamp server 2.5

Tags: php, phpdesigner

I have installed php designer 8. but I am unable to configure it with wamp server 2.5. error "The server at phpdesigner8 can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed."

Comment: I doubt your question has anything to do with the tag `alex`. Also, this might not be a good fit for stackoverflow.

Comment: could you please tell me where can i post my question

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with php (designer). Don't they have a forum or mail-list? I was tempted to say this is a better fit for superuser or serverfault (because of installation problem, not strictly programming), but probably this is best suited for a product support forum.